# Getting double custom titlebar

Tags: android

I am getting two title bar has below ,i have designed a custom title bar with image and text and used styles.xml to set the theme.I have same titlebar for two screens with different text.
[image]

the code are has below

```
public class ReminderActivity extends Activity {
    Context context;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.reminderlayout);
        getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.reminderlayout);
        ArrayList<GetReminder> list = (ArrayList<GetReminder>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("reminderList");
        System.out.println("size is >>>"+list.size());
    }
}
```

xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="35dip"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/formheader">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Reminder Messages"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>
```

manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.loginscreen"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.sampleapp.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.sampleapp.ItemActivity"
            android:theme="@style/TitleBarTheme" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.sampleapp.ReminderActivity"
            android:theme="@style/TitleBarTheme" >        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

and style.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="titleBarHeading" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
        <item name="android:textSize">17sp</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#444444</item>
    </style>
        <style name="CustomWindowTitleBarBG">
            <item name="android:background">#323331</item>
        </style>
        <style name="TitleBarTheme" parent="android:Theme">
            <item name="android:windowTitleSize">35dip</item>
            <item name="android:windowTitleBackgroundStyle">@style/CustomWindowTitleBarBG</item>
        </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: share your R.layout.reminderlayout layout

Comment: not working out and i did not get ow to check if i am inflating again ?

Comment: i have added in my question

Comment: @Fahim yes u wer right its inflating issue,i removed getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.reminderlayout); ,,but i am not able to set background color has white for the screen apart from title bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> setContentView(R.layout.reminderlayout);
>           getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.reminderlayout);

You are using the same layout file for both the Content View and Title. Create a separate layout files for both

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29215730/server-not-able-to-read-parameters-while-making-a-webservice-connection any idea on this?